# Is it possible to get GC performance counters in windbg?

Tags: debugging, crash, garbage-collection, windbg, performancecounter

I have a crash dump and I would like to see GC performance counters such as:

```
% Time in GC, allocated bytes / sec,
# Induced GC,
# Gen 0 Collections,
# Gen 1 Collections,
# Gen 2 Collections,
```

Is it possible to see these counters from windbg or any other tool but using the crashdump?
At the moment I only know how to do that using Performance Monitor in a live process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance counter data are stored elsewhere, so it is impossible to read them from a process dump.

> "When you run a Data Collector Set, the data that is collected for
> performance counters is stored to a log file (.blg) in the location
> that was defined when the Data Collector Set was created. In Windows
> Performance Monitor, you can view log files to see a visual
> representation of performance counter data."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/administration/monitor-view-performance-counter-data-for-data-collector-set

Comment: Thank you for your answer!